# How to fix Javascript NaN issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code

```
  var total_center_buttons=$('.center_button').length;
  var center_button_height=$('.center_button:first-child').height();
  var total_center_button_height=total_center_buttons + center_button_height;
  alert(total_center_button_height);
```

Here `total_center_button value =3`
and `center_button_height is 40` while alerting them separately.It returns `NaN`. I tried ParseInt also but result is same.Please suggest me the solution.
Thanks in advance.
Krishna

Comment: Check `isNaN(123)` it will return true or false then you can do further

Comment: you try adding `undefined` to `int`

Comment: Where is total_center_button_height ???

Comment: do you mean `total_center_buttons` instead of `total_center_button_height` in `center_button_height + total_center_button_height`?

Comment: yes i just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mate,
there's a typo in your post. Notice the code line where you assign the value to total_center_button_height

```
var total_center_button_height = center_button_height + total_center_button_height;
```

That's where the problem is, the variable to the right of the addition operation (total_center_button_height) does not exist yet. Replace that line with...

```
var total_center_button_height = center_button_height + total_center_buttons;
```

Pretty straight forward

Hope it helps

Leo

Comment: Yeah, it helped.  `if you are adding value which not exists yet you will get NaN error` i have fixed this by assigning 0.

Answer (score 3):

We have to guess, since you haven't quoted the DOM, but my guess is that `$('.center_button:first-child')` doesn't match any elements. Calling `height()` on an empty set returns `undefined`. When you try to add it to the number from the previous line, you get `NaN`.

I suspect you didn't want `:first-child`, but rather

```
var center_button_height=$('.center_button').first().height();
```

...but again without seeing the DOM, it's hard to say. To avoid repeated DOM lookups, you'd do this:

```
var buttons = $('.center_button');
var total_center_buttons = buttons.length;
var center_button_height = buttons.first().height();
var total_center_button_height = total_center_buttons + center_button_height;
alert(total_center_button_height);
```

`.center_button:first-child` will only match an element that **both** has the class `center_button` *and* is the first child of its parent element. My suggestion above is based on the assumption that you really wanted the first of the buttons, and that the buttons aren't the first thing in their parent.

Finally: That `+` in

```
var total_center_button_height = total_center_buttons + center_button_height;
```

looks suspicious. Again without seeing the markup it's hard to say, but you may have meant `*` there.

Comment: @KrishnaKarki: All due respect, I'm afraid I don't believe the edit, I think it's observational error. If you really had `3` and `40`, `+` would work correctly. For instance: The first version of your question showed the wrong variable in the line with the `+`, so perhaps you're running a copy of the code with that variable.

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to write this

```
var total_center_button_height=center_button_height + total_center_buttons;
  alert(total_center_button_height);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check for "isNaN" function, this is to check whether the parameter is number or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
      var total_center_buttons = $('.center_button').length > 0 ? $('.center_button').length : 0;
      if(total_center_buttons !=0){
         var center_button_height=$('.center_button:first-child').height();
         var total_center_button_height = center_button_height + total_center_button_height;
         alert(total_center_button_height);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing this:

```
var total_center_button_height=center_button_height + total_center_button_height;
```

i.e. `total_center_button_height` is used in the same line where it is declared. At this time it is undefined.

i guess, you should be doing:

```
var total_center_button_height=center_button_height + total_center_buttons;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var total_center_buttons=$('.center_button').length;
if (typeof total_center_buttons != 'undefined') { 
  var center_button_height=$('.center_button:first-child').height();
  var total_center_button_height=total_center_buttons + center_button_height;
  alert(total_center_button_height);
}
```